# Creating a TSQL query to make a report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am in the process of creating a report from the data I have stored in my database; just a little stuck on the next piece of it.

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b8d8/1) of my structure

The report is run every Friday. It gets all records from the table that are within the last 7 days (since it was last reported).

The piece I need to add to my query is only get me records where the `SUM` of `awardValue` exceeds $75 in the current year.

I have it pulling my records for the time frame (since last report) but need to include that other piece.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The `sum(awardValue)` based on what grouping? Employee?

Comment: yeah, the employee column - sorry forgot to add that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't care about the Award status when you calculate sum -

```
Select Main.*
from main
INNER JOIN(
SELECt EMPLOYEE,SUM(AWARDVALUE) SUM
FROM MAIN
WHERE YEAR(AWARDDATE) = YEAR(GetDate())
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE
HAVING SUM(AWARDVALUE)>75) EMPLIMIT
    ON Main.EMPLOYEE = EMPLIMIT.EMPLOYEE
Where awardStatus = '1' AND awardDate BETWEEN GetDate() - 7 AND GetDate()
```

Modified query to Pull in SUM with results and TaxIt Column

```
Select Main.*,EmployeeSum, 
CASE WHEN EmployeeSum>75 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS TaxIt
from main
INNER JOIN(
SELECt EMPLOYEE,SUM(AWARDVALUE) EmployeeSum
FROM MAIN
WHERE YEAR(AWARDDATE) = YEAR(GetDate())
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE) EMPLIMIT
    ON Main.EMPLOYEE = EMPLIMIT.EMPLOYEE
Where awardStatus = '1' AND awardDate BETWEEN GetDate() - 7 AND GetDate()
```

Comment: This seems like its working - Does the duplicate employee column have to be in there at the end? The table already contains this but if needed i will leave it

Comment: Updated query to get what u need.

Comment: And also tweaked your date comparisons a bit.

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: I know this is out of the original post now but I realized a mistake I made. I need to pull all the data from the WHERE clause like it is, and the SUM part just needs to be another column in the table. When this report is sent to Payroll, if the SUM is greater than 75, we need to indicate that it needs to be taxed. So if we can add the SUM as a column and then if the SUM is greater than 75, add a column called "TaxIt" with the value of `Yes` (all others less than 75 for the year are values of `No`

Comment: Correct, we just want to know once the employee has exceeded $75 for the current year

Answer (score -2):

for this you need to put after the group query the next.

```
SELECT A,B,C, SUM(D)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY A,B,C
HAVING sum(awardValue) > 75
```